# How can I make my question On topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I asked this question [Effects of microwaves on optical properties of human eye](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98731/effects-of-microwaves)  a few days ago. I really asked some offtopic things but now i've edited it appropriately. But it is still closed.
 So how should edit this to make it on topic?

---

Addendum: I have edited my question further, is it on topic now?

Answer (score 5):

Questions 1 and 2 are biology, not physics. We can put upper bounds on the physical effects of something, but it is up to biologists to determine if that is harmful to the organism. These questions are also marginally on-topic for [at least one technical site](https://superuser.com/questions/718650/paranoid-parent-wifi-safe-for-baby) and definitely on-topic for [the local site for general skeptical inquiries](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/are-wifi-waves-harmful).

Questions 3 and 4 can be made on-topic here, but they should be **separate** questions. 3 should be phrased in a way to ask about conceptually how microwaves heat living (i.e. water-rich, organic) material. 4 should ask about whether such frequencies are focused by the eye (note that the vitreous humor is at least as important as the lens proper in humans, the former being essentially water as far as physics is concerned, the latter a crystal in some sense).

Again, it is not for physics to say what the harm is, *unless* you provide the biology necessary for that judgment. For example, if you give a correspondence between electrons ejected from DNA and cancer rate, a physicist can tell you something like "sitting next to a cell tower will cause XXX excess displaced electrons per DNA strand per day due to thermal motions."

I make no guarantees though that these questions have not been asked already. You should check those linked questions in the comments.

Comment: I don't want to ask how microwaves cause heating. I want to ask how ***much*** heating microwaves cause and how to calculate it. It is a homework question because i don't want to learn the concept of dielectric heating i want to learn how to calculate it. Secondly I am not asking the effect on eyes by focused radiation i am asking the effects of an usual Horn antenna used in college labs. Thanks for your answer i am going to delete the 1st and 2nd part.

Comment: I have edited my question from a while. Isn't it on topic now?

Answer (score 4):

My personal pet peeve here is that you *still* have four distinct questions.

**One question per "question", already!**

Nor is "teach me an entire sub-discipline" properly scoped for a Stack Exchange site, and that seems to be the nature of your question.

Comment: So how should i edit this to make it on topic?